# How can I rewrite a subdomain to Magento 1.9 category?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I would like to rewrite a URL with a subdomain to a Magento category. For example, I would like to write the URL:

```
godiva.my_magento_store.com
```

to

```
magento_store.com/godiva.html
```

or even better

```
my_magento_store.com/godiva
```

More than willing to play with both Magento and webserver configuration.

My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on Apache versus Nginx you will end up with different rewrites.  But I would make a vhost for subdomain, first.  Then put the rewrite or redirect under that vhost to go to the proper sub-page/category.

The docs on Nginx rewrites are here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Apache is here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html though you'll have just as much luck with the 2 trillion links about Apache rewrites through Google :)